# How to detect if some function is available in a library at configuration time?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Some libraries exposes functions and types inconsistently depending on the target platform. Notably `libc` and `nix` does that.

How do I detect at configuration time if some function, like `libc::mmap64` or `libc::posix_fallocate` is made available by the crate?

I understand I can't `#[cfg()]` based on a const value exported by the library, nor the library can export a configuration option up to the user. I guess I would have to use `build.rs` to detect it, but I am not sure how.

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration time"? And what do you mean by "detect"? Is your question "how do I use those features only if they're available?"?

Comment: By "configuration time" I mean the time when `rustc` evaluates the `#[cfg()]` directives. By "detect" I mean to be able to make decisions at the configuration time about what parts of my code to enable.

Comment: And why doesn't `#[cfg(target_os = "<target_os that libc::mmap64 is available on>")]` work?

Comment: It does, but I would prefer to delegate the task of tracking the huge list of ever-changing POSIX-ish platforms that supports 64 bits `mmap`s to `libc`.

Comment: At least for `mmap64` that "huge" list is only:

`#[cfg(not(target_env = "musl"))]` according to the [libc source](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/src/libc/unix/linux_like/mod.rs.html#1787-1811), and for `posix_fallocate` you have `#[cfg_attr(not(any(target_env = "musl", target_env = "ohos")), ...]` as seen [here](https://docs.rs/libc/latest/src/libc/unix/linux_like/linux/mod.rs.html#4239-4242)

Comment: @PatientPenguin That is wrong. You are looking at the condition only for Linux-based systems. Neither applies to macos or other unix/POSIX systems.

Comment: @lvella could you point me to the documentation of `libc` that has `mmap64` for non-linux systems?

Comment: @PatientPenguin rust's `libc`, as a rule, doesn't document its functions, because it is meant to be a direct ABI compatible FFI to the system's C library, so you should refer to the system's C library directly for documentation. That said, if I want my application to work portably across different systems, using your suggestion of `#[cfg(not(target_env = "musl"))]` to test for `mmap64` would break the build in macOS and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC #2523](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2523-cfg-path-version.html) specified a notation `#[cfg(accessible(path))]`, that can be used to do something like you want (amongst other things): `#[cfg(accessible(libc::mmap64))]` will be on only if `libc::mmap64()` is, well, accessible.

However, this RFC is not completely implemented at this time. Namely, the part of `#[cfg(accessible)]` is not, due to technical difficulties.

However, [PR #69870](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/69870) implemented something similar: `#[cfg_accessible(path)]`.

However, as per my testings I'm not sure it actually works for this case, and also, it cannot be combined with cfg operations - meaning e.g. it cannot be negated: you cannot implement some logic for when something *isn't* available.

So, your best bet is to `#[cfg()]` for the platforms this is implemented on. This is what everyone does.